# React - Dispatch onload and read value

Tags: reactjs

In a React application, I dispatch environment values to the store and then check whether one of these values is true or false. The code looks something like this

```
 const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

 const hasOpenia = useSelector(openiaapi);

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApis = async () => {
      await dispatch(
        setApis({
          openia: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OpenAI,
          pexels: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_Pexels,
          google: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GooglePlace,
        })
      );
    };
    fetchApis();
    if (!!!hasOpenia) {
      setVisible(true);
    }
  }, [dispatch, hasOpenia]);
```

```
if (!!!hasOpenia) {
   setVisible(true);
}
```

It is always undefined. I think there is a problem with dispatching actions. I need to wait for the value and then check it, instead of trying to read hasOpenia without waiting. So, anybody know what´s the proper way?